# Jacobian elliptic surface $J(\mathcal{E})$ for a given elliptic surface $\mathcal{E}$ without a section.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an elliptic surface over $\mathbb{P}^1$ without a section. What is a right definition of its Jacobian elliptic surface $J(\mathcal{E})$? Is it unique up to birational isomorphisms over $\mathbb{P}^1$? How can I find its Weierstrass equation $\mathcal{W}$?

Comment: Maybe you should find something in the book _Enriques surfaces I_ by Cossec and Dolgachev.

Comment: Let I understand the definition. How can I find Weierstrass equation W?

Comment: Let $\mathcal E\to \mathbb P^1$ be an elliptic surface. Let $\eta$ be the generic point of the scheme $\mathbb P^1$, and let $X = \mathcal E_\eta$ be the generic fibre of the elliptic fibration. Note that $X$ is a genus one curve over the function field $K= K(\mathbb P^1)$ of $\mathbb P^1$. Let $ J= \mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/K}$ be the Jacobian of $X$ over $K$. That's the "right" definition of the Jacobian of the generic fibre. Finding a Weierstrass equation can be quite tricky depending on your situation.

Comment: My elliptic surface $\mathcal{E}$ is associated with the nonsingular intersection of two quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Also, $\mathcal{E}$ is geometrically rational and has the section over the purely inseparable extension of degree 2. Can I find Weierstrass equation in this case?